# How do I refuse any changes in the input box if I click the cancel button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have an input box that is disabled unless i click the edit button which enables to type in the input box, by clicking the edit button, the save and cancel button will appear. If i click the cancel button, the input box will be disabled again.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="savechanges" id="savechanges">Save Changes</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="edit" id="edit">Edit Info</button>

<script>
$('#edit').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#savechanges, #cancel').show();
        $("#target :input").prop("disabled", false);
    });

    $('#cancel').click(function () {
        $('#edit').show();
        $('#savechanges, #cancel').hide();
        $("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);
    });
</script>
```

what im trying to do is if i click the edit button, for example i type something in there and then i want to cancel it so i click the cancel button, as what ive said above it will disabled the input box. but that something in there is still there. that is not suppose to be there already since i cancelled it. also if for example the input box has already a value displayed inside it and i edited in but i want to cancel so it will go back to that value. can anyone help me pls i hope you get my point

Comment: Save the value of the input when the user clicks `edit`. After the user clicks `cancel`, restore the input value as what is saved.

Comment: @HaoWu do you have code for that? that  would be a big help

Comment: I've added the code as an answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this

```
$('#cancel').click(function () {
        $('#edit').show();
        $('#savechanges, #cancel').hide();
        $("#target :input").val('');
        $("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);
    });
```

Comment: this will make the input box empty if i click the cancel button. what if the input box has value displayed and i want it to display again if i click the cancel button. not make it empty

Comment: In that case you must need to store the displayed value in a hidden field/ sesson/ viewstate. When cancel button click set the stored value in input box.

Answer (score 0):

Save the value of the input when the user clicks edit. After the user clicks cancel, restore the input value as what is saved.

```js
let storedValue= '';

$('#edit').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    storedValue = $("#target :input").val();
    $('#savechanges, #cancel').show();
    $("#target :input").prop("disabled", false);
});

$('#cancel').click(function () {
    $('#edit').show();
    $('#savechanges, #cancel').hide();
    $("#target :input").val(storedValue);
    $("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: i tried doing this and, when i click cancel. the input box will have the value "on" why is that

Comment: @ErfamaeFermo Did you have other inputs in your document? Try a more specific selector like `$('#target input[type="text"]')`

Comment: @ErfamaeFermo How the 5 inputs look like. Can you include them in the question?

Comment: thank you so much for helping! i finally got the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

after searching for the right answer i found out and this works for me.i just change my button type for the cancel button. instead of

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

i changed the type into:

```
 <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" value="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```